# Add current class to on page menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I want to add an active class to an on page menu. So it's not a default menu with different pages, but just links on the same page. How can I add a class to the last clicked menu item?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arvanderkamp/KUfxF/

And my javascript so far:

```
$(function() {
    $(".elevator a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});        
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#ondernemen"]').click(function() {
        $('#ondernemen').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#groeien"]').click(function() {
        $('#groeien').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#spelen"]').click(function() {
        $('#spelen').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').click(function() {
        $('#ontdekken').slideDown(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
  $('a[href="#ondernemen"]').click(function() {
     $(".active").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#ondernemen').slideDown(1000);
    $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
    $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
    $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KUfxF/3/)

You can use `.addClass()` for adding the active class.

`$(".active").removeClass("active");` this line will remove the class `active` from all the elements.

Use those 2 line in your every click event code.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted though, your answer is even more in depth than mine :/

Comment: Is there also an easy way to combine $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000); $('#groeien').slideUp(1000); $('#spelen').slideUp(1000); to just one line of code?

Comment: Is it also possible to add an (extra) active class to the element #ontdekken, before one of the links is clicked? The content of this element is shown when the page loads

Comment: $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').addClass("active"). Put this line on $(document).ready(

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this in each of your functions?

```
$('a[href="#ondernemen"]').click(function() {
    $('.yourClass').removeClass('yourClass');
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KUfxF/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".elevator a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
$(".elevator a").removeClass();
$(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be much better if you explained how it works and why it is a good and useful answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove classes as shown below

```
$('a[href="#ondernemen"]').click(function() {
    $('.yourClass').removeClass('yourClass');
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
    ////Your code
});
```

More information :-

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 0):

Access dom element which invoked event by `e.currentTarget` property and add new class to it by `.addClass()`

```
  $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').click(function(e) {
    $('#ontdekken').slideDown(1000);
    $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
    $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("back");        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the class you want, and use event delegation to avoid attaching to many handlers that do the same action.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.elevator').click(function(e) {
        var $t = $(e.target);
        if($t.is('a'))
        {
            $t.addClass('activeClass')
                .closest('div').siblings()
                   .find('a').removeClass('activeClass');
            $($t[0].hash).slideDown(1000).siblings().slideUp(1000);   
            e.preventDefault()
        }

    });
    $('body').on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
            if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KUfxF/9/)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The elevator element also slides up when I click one of the links

Comment: @arvanderkamp You may have messed up the code `:s` .. I just tested it again and elevator element never slides (FF, IE, Chrome) what a pity ... the code is much lighter this way `;)`

Comment: Yes I think it conflicts with the rest of my code. My knowlegde of jQuery sucks, so I have to pass this one. :( Do you know if its possible to add an (extra) active class to the element #ontdekken, before one of the links is clicked? The content of this element is shown when the page loads

Comment: So you would like to add a class to it when page has loaded ?

Comment: Yes, that's right! But it has to disappear when i click one of the other links

Comment: just add `$('#ontdekken').addClass('cssClass');` inside the ready function (but not inside click handlers) ... Inside my code it would be on between the 1rst and 2nd lines

Comment: May I suggest you to post your new code ? then I will be able to turn it like i wrote it above + giving ontdekken a class on page load `^^`

Comment: It had to be: $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').addClass('active');

Comment: Sure since it's not actualy an id but the value of the href attribute ... Saying "#ontdekken" means the node with an id "ontdekken" Your question was not clear enough, I'm glad you found out on your own `:p`

Comment: You're welcome, I wish you could take advantage of my code and get ride of the redundant code your revision contains.. `:/`